# In MySQL SELECT statement, how can a derived field utilise the value of another field in the SELECT list?

Tags: mysql, sql

In a MySQL SELECT statement, how can a derived field utilise the value of another field in the SELECT list?

For example, when running the following query:

```
SELECT
 'tim' AS first_name
,first_name || ' example' AS full_name;
```

I would expect the result to be:

```
first_name, full_name
tim       , tim example
```

Instead, I get the following **error**:

```
Unknown column 'first_name' in 'field list'.
```

Is there a way I can reference another column?

Thanks
Turgs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you have to repeat it or use a derived table.

```
select *, concat(first_name,  ' example') as full_name
 from (
select
 'tim' as first_name ) as t
```

Answer (score 4):

You either wrap the query as a subquery:

```
SELECT
    first_name
  , first_name || ' example' AS full_name
FROM
  ( SELECT
        'tim' AS first_name
      , ... 
    FROM ...
    ...
  ) AS tmp
```

or duplicate the code:

```
SELECT
    'tim' AS first_name
  , 'tim' || ' example' AS full_name
```

Answer (score 4):

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html

> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.

You cannot reference a column whose value has not yet been determined.

Comment: This is relevant but not exactly what the OP asks for.